# dpdk tcp checksum failed occasionally in virtio scenario

Tags: dpdk

i'm using dpdk 21.11 and observed tcp checksum failed occasionally in virtio scenario used dpdk-pdump:
capture by client (send package): tcp.checksum is correct
capture by server (receive package): tcp.checksum is 0.
The following figure shows the Wireshark screenshot:
https://github.com/JiangHeng12138/dpdk-issue/issues/2

i am not use tcp checksum offload feature,  tcp checksum is performed by the TCP/IP protocol stack.
mbuf->ol_flags is 0, when tcp checksum failed.

Please tell me some debugging methods to solve this issue.